# No logs for DFS Replication on Domain Controller

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2019, dfs-r

I was testing monitoring DFSR event logs on my DCs and figured there are no logs after event 1210 (The DFS Replication service successfully set up an RPC listener for incoming replication requests.) Unfortunately i cleared the log yesterday and didnt save it but i can see on my other DC that the last event 5004 occured on 03.10.2022 after i restarted the DC but since that nothing. Repadmin /showrepl and /replsum show no issues. Is this normal behaviour? Do i need to change something on my DCs so that these logs are properly logged?

Environment:
DC01 Windows 2012R2
DC02 Windows 2019 (one with log issues) holding FSMO roles
Both servers are in the same network and there is no firewall between them
Both servers are virtual machines